# Python (Django) Error importing a module into a bat

Tags: python, django, batch-file

I have a problem running my bat file or I'm using a python program (Django).

Here is the error message at runtime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chemin\import_engagementD.py", line 5, in <module>
    from postes.models import EngagementD
ImportError: No module named 'postes'
FIN du Scripthere
```

Here is my bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Script en cours
python chemin\import_engagementD.py
ECHO FIN du Script
pause
```

And finally the tree of my project:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHv8r.png)

Here is my import_engagementD.py file:

```
import os
import csv
import django.model
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from django.conf import settings
from postes.models import EngagementD
from pprint import pprint
import unicodedata

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Commande d'importation automatique de Engagement"

    # A command must define handle()
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # Si vous utilisez des chemins relatifs, Django risque de ne pas trouver votre fichier lignes.csv
        # Partez toujours de settings.BASE_DIR qui est la racine de votre projet
        cheminRegion = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "postes/management/commands/Donnees/TableauEngDistribparRegion.csv")
        cheminGMR = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "postes/management/commands/Donnees/TableauEngDistribparGMR.csv")

        compteurRegion = 0
        compteurGMR = 0

        with open(cheminRegion) as csvfile:
            lignes = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            for ligne in lignes:
                # utiliser get_or_create pour éviter de recréer des lignes qui existent déjà
                # Utilisation d'un compteur pour recuperer les lignes nécessaire
                if(compteurRegion >= 1 and compteurRegion < 9):
                    print(compteurRegion)
                    pprint(ligne)
                    if (ligne[0] == "Total"):
                        ligne = EngagementD.objects.get_or_create(tauxNA=ligne[7][:-1].replace(",", "."), tauxA=ligne[5][:-1].replace(",", "."), tauxD=ligne[3][:-1].replace(",", "."), region="France")
                    else:
                        ligne = EngagementD.objects.get_or_create(tauxNA=ligne[7][:-1].replace(",", "."), tauxA=ligne[5][:-1].replace(",", "."), tauxD=ligne[3][:-1].replace(",", "."), region=unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', (ligne[0]).encode('ASCII','ignore').decode('UTF-8')))
                compteurRegion+=1

        with open(cheminGMR) as csvfile:
            lignes = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            for ligne in lignes:
                # utiliser get_or_create pour éviter de recréer des lignes qui existent déjà
                # Utilisation d'un compteur pour recuperer les lignes nécessaire
                if(compteurGMR >= 1 and compteurGMR < 31):
                    pprint(compteurGMR)
                    pprint(ligne)
                    ligne, created = EngagementD.objects.get_or_create(tauxNA=ligne[8][:-1].replace(",","."), tauxA=ligne[6][:-1].replace(",","."), tauxD=ligne[4][:-1].replace(",","."), gmr=unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', (ligne[1][4:len(ligne[1])])).encode('ASCII', 'ignore').decode('UTF-8').replace(" ", ""))
                compteurGMR+=1
```

Comment: Well, there you have it _"No module named 'postes'"_ Did you import the module?

Comment: Okay but how can I get it to be recognized when I'm running the bat, otherwise the program works fine when I run from pycharm.

Comment: Please specify the location of **batch file**. Also provide the code of **import_engagementD.py** so that we can check the issue.

Comment: My batch file is in my Desktop.

Comment: What is **chemin\import_engagementD.py**? What this does? Where is your Django project? Specify the location of your Django project & batch file. Also mention, how you are executing your batch, using Command prompt or just by clicking on it. If your project is for public use then you can upload it on **Github** and provide the link.

Comment: First of all, sorry for answering so late. path \ import_engagementD.py is the path to the file "import_engagementD.py". My django project is in "C: \ Users \ Folder" and my batch file is in my desktop. I can't upload this project because its private for a company, sorry.